# MacOS QuickTime video conversion through AVFoundation

Tags: macos, avfoundation, quicktime, core-video

I am using AVFoundation to decode video files on macOS. I noticed a lot of files which couldn't be played on QuickTime without a conversion:
[image]

Those files couldn't be decoded using AVFoundation.

My question is:

Is there a way to programmatically do this conversion using AVFoundation, CoreVideo or another framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QTMovieModernizer is your friend in that case.